# Add data source to available options under Data Source Name

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, odbc, datasource

I need to connect to a SQL Server database that isn't currently listed in the "Data Source Name" field.  I've created plenty of OLE DB (ADO) data sources before but this is the first time I've had to use an ODBC (RDO) connection.

the user that sent me this has her information saved in the report and it work from her computer only.  She's handing this out to other users and of course it prompts them with the below image (and the DB in question isn't listed).  Any help as to how I can get that DB listed would be a great help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the ODBC connection on her local PC in your local environment.  Exporting to a .reg format is an easy way to copy the connections without going through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the `ODBC` connection that establishes the connection to database.. before creating take care to use the same `DSN name` that was used to develop the report.

Follow below steps to create a ODBC connection:

1. `Go to run---> type ODBCAD32 --> User tab ---> click Add --> There select the type of database driver ---> Then you get the window where you can add DSN Name and all other fields`

Before doing above process make sure that you have all database details with you.

2. After creating DSN in the window you posted you will get the DSN name there select that DSN